# Adding to a dictionary in python3 from a txt file with multiple values

Tags: python, dictionary

A homework assignment I have been working on.

I'm currently trying to read in a txt file:

- firstname lastname 01 02 03
- firstname lastname 01 02 03
- firstname lastname 01 02 03
- firstname lastname 01 02 03

Then put the names together and add the numbers. The problem is the way my code is now I "need more than 1 value to unpack" (error) and I am not sure how to do more than 2 values currently.

```
fname = input("Enter the name of the file you want to open: ")
fo = open(fname, "r")

d = {}

for line in fo:
    (key, val) = line.strip().split(":")
    d[key] = int(value)

fo.close()
```

Comment: Your example text input contains no colons, so what exactly are you expecting `.split(":")` to achieve?

Comment: Right, I have been adjusting it trying different ways and I must have left that in there from the previous attempt.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. There's no point showing code that clearly couldn't possibly work and asking why it doesn't.

Comment: I'll have to work on my question asking for the future, this one thankfully is figured out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply write more than two values before the `=` on assignment.
You have five values per line, so you can write

```
fname, lname, val1, val2, val3 = line.strip().split(":")
```

But your error "need more than 1 value to unpack" signals another problem: you only get one value out of your split() and try to put it into two variables. You need to change the `":"` in the call to `.split()` to the character separating the columns in your file. If it's a whitespace the following will work:

```
fname, lname, val1, val2, val3 = line.strip().split(" ")
```

Comment: That did it just like you said, the .split(" ") was the difference along with more variables before the =. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Note that you can leave out `" "` entirely to collapse all consecutive whitespace into a single split.

Comment: That's right, but it depends on the format of his file if that's what he wants. `'1 2  3'.split(' ')` => `['1', '2', '', '3']` and `'1 2  3'.split()` => `['1', '2', '3']`